# Paging Graph Data

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have checked multiple paging threads on Stack and I was not able to make a functional replica of the code.

I know in the following case, Graph returns 200 items per page, and if I wanna `foreach` all of the items I need to switch to the next page. Please check the following code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Always throws an exception in the catch where the `NextPageRequest.GetAsync()` is being called.

Result of this code is that only 200 of 3xx items are removed.

```cs
var deleteListItems = new List<Microsoft.Graph.ListItem>();
var deleteListItemsPage = await graphServiceClient
    .Sites[siteUrl]
    .Lists[listName]
    .Items
    .Request(deleteQueryOptions)
    .GetAsync();

deleteListItems.AddRange(deleteListItemsPage.CurrentPage);

do
{
    foreach (var deleteItem in deleteListItemsPage)
    {
        awaitTasks.Add(graphServiceClient
            .Sites[siteUrl]
            .Lists[listName]
            .Items[deleteItem.Id]
            .Request()
            .DeleteAsync());
    }

    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(awaitTasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROOR executing the tasks");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Another PAGE of List Items successfully deleted");

    try
    {
        deleteListItemsPage = await deleteListItemsPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        deleteListItems.AddRange(deleteListItemsPage.CurrentPage);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There is no NextPageRequest for deleting items or ERROR occured.");
    }
} while (deleteListItemsPage.NextPageRequest != null);
```

Comment: Depending on how the skipToken works, it is possible that by deleting all the items from the first page, it may be invalidating the skipToken.  I would recommend walking all the pages, collecting the Ids and then walking the list of Ids and deleting them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations:

1. The `Task.WaitAll` pattern is technically correct but in practice, it is prone to human error. You should always use the `async`/`await` pattern unless there is a very compelling technical reason to do otherwise. It will save you a lot of headaches.
2. You should never use an empty `catch { }` clause unless you want to eat any exception without warning or context (FTR, you *don't* want this). At the very least, you should catch the generic `System.Exception` and assign it to a variable (`catch (Exception e) {}`), even if the only you thing you do with it log the exception to the console (`catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }`).
3. When you know an object has the potential to be `null`, you should always *check for* `null` rather than relying on a Try/Catch. The Try/Catch pattern relies on Exceptions which are a *lot* more expensive than a simple null check.

For a scenario like this, a better pattern would something along the lines of this:

```cs
private async Task DeleteItems()
{
    // Construct the HTTP Request but DO NOT execute it just yet
    var deleteListItemsRequest = graphServiceClient
        .Sites[siteUrl]
        .Lists[listName]
        .Items
        .Request(deleteQueryOptions);

    // This loop is for iterating over the pages
    do
    {
        // Populate the page by executing the HTTP request
        var deleteListItemsPage = deleteListItemsRequest.GetAsync();

        // Iterate over the current page
        foreach (var listItem in deleteListItemsPage.CurrentPage)
        {
            // Execute the delete and wait for the response
            await graphServiceClient
                .Sites[siteUrl]
                .Lists[listName]
                .Items[deleteItem.Id]
                .Request()
                .DeleteAsync();
        }

        // Check for additional pages
        if (deleteListItemsPage.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            // If we have an additional page, assign it to the
            // same HTTP Request object. Again, we DO NOT execute 
            // yet. It will get executed at the top of the loop
            deleteListItemsRequest = deleteListItemsPage.NextPageRequest;
        }
        else
        {
            // If we don't have an additional page, set the current
            // request to null so we can use this to trigger an exit
            // from the loop
            deleteListItemsRequest = null;
        }

        // Check if we have a Graph request, if not break out of the loop
    } while (deleteListItemsRequest != null);
}
```

Comment: In another question I had recommended to parallize the requests because the problem was it was taking too long to delete all the items.  Issuing the deletes in parallel removes a whole lot of waiting around.  I agree it can be tricky to deal with Task.WaitAll, especially dealing with failures.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the DeleteListItems list because that's not the list he is iterating over.  I suspect he is just keeping track of all the items that have been deleted.

Comment: Marc, thanks for your suggestions and help I really appreciate it :-) Your code works fine, but the way it is removing 1 by 1 takes so long. I have adjusted it to use the Task.WaitAll even though you do not recommend it and it seems to work just fine and fast. I will keep it in mind and will observe it's behavior for a bit.

Comment: Nothing wrong with parallelism (so long as you mitigate against potential throttling), it's just easier to debug a linear flow so it's normally where I recommend starting. Scale is absolutely a valid technical reason for doing this.